# How should I deal with the fact that currencies change in value in relation to each other when bookkeeping?

Tags: calculation, bookkeeping

I have made a bookkeeping system for myself. At its core, it consists of a database table with these fields:

```
timestamp_for_when_it_was_inserted_into_database
timestamp_for_when_the_transaction_happened
amount
currency_code
amount_in_EUR_when_it_happened
```

So, for example, if I make a Bitcoin transaction of 0.005 BTC to somebody today, I would enter it into my system as:

```
blabla, blabla, -0.005, BTC, 500
```

(With 500 here being a made-up value for how much 0.005 BTC is in EUR at the moment when it was recorded into the system.)

Now, over time, if I want to see how much money I have in BTC, it's simple:

```
SELECT sum(amount);
```

That calculates all the Bitcoin amounts and gives me the current "balance" in Bitcoin. (Of course, I'm simplifying it here for the purpose of asking this question. In reality, there are many more fields with further data.)

However, if I want to know the current balance in EUR, and do this:

```
SELECT sum(amount_in_EUR_when_it_happened);
```

... then the answer will not be the right amount, because the EUR price has gone up and down during this time, causing these amounts to no longer correspond to the current Bitcoin amounts. As a result, the "balance" figure will technically be correct with the data available in the table, but it will not correspond to the current amount of Euros that I own as Bitcoin, based on the current Bitcoin-to-Euro exchange rate.

Is there an elegant way to solve this? The only solutions I can think of are very ugly and annoying:

1. I could fetch and loop through all the relevant records every time I load my view, and use current exchange rates to calculate a new sum. This requires that I'm connected to the Internet to be able to fetch the exchange rates, and may take several seconds depending on how many currencies are involved and other reasons. That's slow and annoying.
2. I could put in a new column called `amount_in_EUR_with_current_rate`, and then have my system continuously loop through and update these cells in my table around the clock, just for the possibility that I will at some point load my bookkeeping "view". This will continue to work if my connection goes down (for a while), and will be instant, but it seems very wasteful, even though I do caching and don't make network requests for each row time. I don't like this solution either.

Maybe I'm fundamentally thinking about this the wrong way? Is my current "balance algorithm" called something in financial terms? Maybe something like "naive balance" or "technical balance", as opposed to "live balance" or "true balance"?

How is this kind of problem typically solved? Note that it has very little to do with Bitcoin specifically, as fiat currencies also change their rates all the time. (Albeit usually not by as much.)

Comment: I would take `amount_in_EUR_when_it_happened` as just what it says: the snapshot of reality **when the transaction happened**.  Only use that column for determining your cost basis; nothing else.

Comment: Voting to close. This is either an accounting specific question or - more likely - a software development question much more as a question about personal finance. MTM (market to Market) reevaluation of assets is a standard element in most commercial accounting packages. The 2 questions are both way more about software development than anything else.

Comment: @TomTom It is an accounting question IMO, but it's accounting of a person's finances, so is that not allowed here?

Comment: Really what happens is you gain/lose 0.005 BTC, and then the BTC-to-EUR exchange rate fluctuates which causes your net worth (measured in EUR) to fluctuate as well. But you could also measure your net worth in BTC in which case it's your EUR assets that are causing the fluctuation.

Comment: @user253751 It is WAY more programming than accounting. And this is not a page for software development questions. Also there are TONS of tradeoffs depending on db size.

Comment: @TomTom Nah, it's not programming - you would have the exact same question with pen-and-paper accounts!

Comment: @TomTom Paper equivalent: "However, if I want to know the current balance in EUR, and add up the 'amount in EUR when it happened' column, then the answer will not be the right amount ...". The asker is perfectly familiar with how to use the database software, but they are asking about the underlying accounting concepts. Perhaps they should remove the specific SQL code so the focus is more clearly on the accounting.

Comment: @Samo [someone on the meta site agrees](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2951/was-this-question-incorrectly-closed/2953) that you should remove the specific references to programming and then this is on topic. E.g. don't talk about loops, just say you'll add up all the numbers in this column.